# Xamarin.Forms cant see my generated code on an emulated pixel 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, .net-6.0

I am new to app programming and i try to get my feet wet. My Problem is i cant see anything in my emulated Pixel 5. For context im using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise and a blank Xamarin.Forms solution.

Here is my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace App2
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void OnBurgerButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SliderFrame.WidthRequest == 0)
            {
                await SliderFrame.TranslateTo(200, 0, 250, Easing.SinOut);
                SliderFrame.WidthRequest = 200;
            }
            else
            {
                await SliderFrame.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250, Easing.SinIn);
                SliderFrame.WidthRequest = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="BurgerButton" Text="☰" Clicked="OnBurgerButtonClicked" />

        <StackLayout x:Name="SliderStackLayout" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Frame x:Name="SliderFrame" CornerRadius="0" HasShadow="false" BackgroundColor="Red" WidthRequest="0">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Anwenderkorrekturen" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    <Label Text="Gesamtansicht" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Could anyone maybe help me with my issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Remove `WidthRequest="0"`.  Or set it to a big enough number.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. Did you make changes in any other place? Try a new project, put your code in MainPage without any other change, does it work well?